# PHPMailer send empty mail

Tags: php, email

I use `phpmailer` library to send email with attachment

The body of this mail is an `html`

This i mys code:

```
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->From = $email;
$mail->FromName = $staffname;
$mail->addAddress($email,$staffname);
//Provide file path and name of the attachments
for($i=0;$i<count($files);$i++){    
 $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'][$i],
                      $_FILES['myfile']['name'][$i]); //Filename is optional
}
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = "New Task";
$mail->Body = "<h1 align='center'>YOU HAVE A NEW TASK</h1>
    <table  width='100%' border='1'>
    <tr bgcolor='#f7ac01' align='center'>
    <td>Date</td>
    <td>Description</td>
    <td>Status</td>
    <td>Type</td>
    <td>Frequency</td>
    <td>Priority</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align='center'>
    <td>$date</td>
    <td>$desc</td>
    <td>$status</td>
    <td>$type</td>
    <td>$frequency</td>
    <td>$priority</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <h2 align='center'>PLEASE CHECK IT </h3>
    ";
$mail->AltBody = "";
if(!$mail->send()) 
{
    header("location:add-tasks.php?msg=33");//Mail Not Send
}else{
header("location:add-tasks.php?msg=10");//Add Complete
}
```

The problem is i receive an empty body mail without any attachment

After a certain search i found i should use

```
$mail->Body
```

Not

```
$mail->body
```

And i should use `$mail->isHTML(true);` but this is my code already and this didn't give me any help.

How can i solve this problem to receive a mail with a full body information and attachment using `phpmailer` library??!!

Answer (score 0):

Not `$mail->body` use `$mail->MsgHTML`:

```
$message = "<h1 align='center'>YOU HAVE A NEW TASK</h1>
<table  width='100%' border='1'>
<tr bgcolor='#f7ac01' align='center'>
<td>Date</td>
<td>Description</td>
<td>Status</td>
<td>Type</td>
<td>Frequency</td>
<td>Priority</td>
</tr>
<tr align='center'>
<td>$date</td>
<td>$desc</td>
<td>$status</td>
<td>$type</td>
<td>$frequency</td>
<td>$priority</td>
</tr>
</table>
<h2 align='center'>PLEASE CHECK IT </h3>
";    
$mail->MsgHTML($message);
```

Comment: also i receive an empty email without any attachment

Comment: did you give attachment name and path

Comment: To add Attachment $mail->addAttachment($path, $name, $encoding, $type);

Comment: this is the path $path = "uploads/"; and the attachment code is put it above

Comment: Try this structure `dirname(__FILE__).'/uploads//filename.doc' `

Comment: it still i can't receive attachment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153127/discussion-between-mohamad-mohamad-and-lavanya-e).

Answer (score 0):

You should try to move your uploaded file `move_uploaded_file` to your file system and attach it to your email later.

Also, you are sending 2 versions of your email [text and html], you are defining that the contents are html `$mail->isHTML(true)` and setting the contents `$mail->Body="body";` but you are also sending a empty variable for text only version of the email `$mail->AltBody='';`

Your email client also must accept an html version of the email, if not it will use the text version.(maybe this is your case.)